# Replacing selected column values of a big data spark dataframe if the ID matches

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes whose schema differs by one column. The below dataframes are just for example.

Dataframe 1:

```
ID Name   Age  Year   Area
1  Alice  20    95     X
2  Bob    30    96     Y
3  Jack   10    98     Z
4  Will   25    99     A
```

Dataframe 2:

```
ID Name   Age  Year   Country
10  Alice  20    95     US
20  Bob    30    96     UK
3  Jack    30    24     DE
4  Will    40    25     ES
```

Now I need a scala code where the Dataframe 2 column "Age" and "Year" changes if the matching ID is found in Dataframe 1. The required dataframe would be as below.

Required Dataframe 2:

```
ID Name   Age  Year   Country
10  Alice  20    95     US
20  Bob    30    96     UK
3   Jack   10    98     DE
4   Will   25    99     ES
```

The real dataframes are huge. I want a scala code snippet which is computationally feasible for big data. Can this be done through simple Join statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a left join for the two dataframes and use `coalesce` function to select the `Age`, `Year` from the `df1` first if not null, otherwise from `df2`

Input:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val data1 = Seq(
        (1, "Alice", 20, 95, "X"),
        (2, "Bob", 30, 96, "Y"),
        (3, "Jack", 10, 98, "Z"),
        (4, "Will", 25, 99, "A")
      )
val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1).toDF("ID", "Name", "Age", "Year", "Area")


val data2 = Seq(
        (10, "Alice", 20, 95, "US"),
        (20, "Bob", 30, 96, "UK"),
        (3, "Jack", 30, 24, "DE"),
        (4, "Will", 40, 25, "ES")
      )
val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2).toDF("ID", "Name", "Age", "Year", "Country")
```

Join the two dataframes:

```scala
df2.join(df1.select("ID", "Age", "Year"), "ID", "left_outer")
    .select(df2("ID"), 
            df2("Name"), 
            coalesce(df1("Age"), df2("Age")).as("Age"), 
            coalesce(df1("Year"), df2("Year")).as("Year"), 
            df2("Country")) 
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+---+----+-------+
| ID| Name|Age|Year|Country|
+---+-----+---+----+-------+
| 10|Alice| 20|  95|     US|
| 20|  Bob| 30|  96|     UK|
|  3| Jack| 10|  98|     DE|
|  4| Will| 25|  99|     ES|
+---+-----+---+----+-------+
```